# How to get data from multidimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var data = [{
  length: 900,
  fields: 3
},{
  length: 1150,
  fields: 4
},{
  length: 1700,
  fields: 5
}];
```

Now I would like to have a function that returns the fields depending on the given length like:

```
function getFields(length) {
   // return "3" if length <= 900
   // return "4" if length <= 1150
   // return "5" if length <= 1700
}
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Will your array be sorted wrt `length`?

Comment: seems like a for loop if data is properly sorted.

Comment: Thanks! The array will be sorted, but there are solutions for both below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define it like so:

```
function getFields(length) {
   var d = data
            .filter(d => d.length <= length)        // get the list of matching objects
            .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)    // sort descending so largest value is at the front of the array
            .shift();                               // get the first element from the array
    return (d !== undefined) ? d.fields : undefined;// if that element exists, return .fields, otherwise undefined
}
```

In action:

```js
var data = [{
    length: 900,
    fields: 3
},{
    length: 1150,
    fields: 4
},{
    length: 1700,
    fields: 5
}];

function getFields(length) {
   var d = data
            .filter(d => d.length <= length)        // get the list of matching objects
            .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)    // sort descending so largest value is at the front of the array
            .shift();                               // get the first element from the array
    return (d !== undefined) ? d.fields : undefined;// if that element exists, return .fields, otherwise undefined
}

var tests = [1700, 1150, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700];
console.log(tests.map(getFields));
```

While I don't know if this is performant enough for your current use case, but it's relatively readable and easy-to-follow (although this could be made more efficient if the data were always ordered by `length`, for instance). If you need something more performant, you could do something like this instead:

```
function getFields(length) {
    let d;
    let i = data.length - 1;

    while (i > -1 && d === undefined) {
        if (data[i].length <= length) {
            d = data[i].fields;
        }
        i -= 1;
    }

    return d;
}
```

In action:

```js
var data = [{
    length: 900,
    fields: 3
},{
    length: 1150,
    fields: 4
},{
    length: 1700,
    fields: 5
}];

function getFields(length) {
    let d;
    let i = data.length - 1;
    
    while (i > -1 && d === undefined) {
        if (data[i].length <= length) {
            d = data[i].fields;
        }
        i -= 1;
    }
    
    return d;
}

var tests = [1700, 1150, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700];
console.log(tests.map(getFields));
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as data is properly sorted, it is a simple for loop

```js
var data = [{
  length: 900,
  fields: 3
},{
  length: 1150,
  fields: 4
},{
  length: 1700,
  fields: 5
}];

function getFields (value) {
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (value <= data[i].length) return data[i].fields;  // exit since we found first match
  }
  return 0; // what ever the default is for no match
}

console.log(800, getFields(800));
console.log(900, getFields(900)); 
console.log(1000, getFields(1000)); 
console.log(1500, getFields(1500)); 
console.log(2000, getFields(2000));
```

or with modern array methods you can use find() which is like a for loop code above under the hood:

```js
var data = [{
  length: 900,
  fields: 3
},{
  length: 1150,
  fields: 4
},{
  length: 1700,
  fields: 5
}];

function getFields (value) {
  var i;
  var match = data.find(function(item) { 
    return value <= item.length
  })
  return match ? match.fields : 0;
}

console.log(800, getFields(800));
console.log(900, getFields(900)); 
console.log(1000, getFields(1000)); 
console.log(1500, getFields(1500)); 
console.log(2000, getFields(2000));
```

Now if the data array is out of order, than it should be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate the `data` and match the conditon

```js
var data = [{
  length: 900,
  fields: 3
},{
  length: 1150,
  fields: 4
},{
  length: 1700,
  fields: 5
}];

   function getFields(len) {
var fields = '';
$.each(data, function(key,value) {
  if(value.length<=len)
     fields = value.fields;
}); 
 return fields;
}

   // call function 
   alert(getFields(1700));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `jQuery` for this, it can be done with e.g. a standard [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) call. Note that this assumes that the data is sorted by `.length` as in your example.

```js
var data = [{
  length: 900,
  fields: 3
}, {
  length: 1150,
  fields: 4
}, {
  length: 1700,
  fields: 5
}];

var value = 950;
var matching = data.find(x => value <= x.length);
var fields = matching ? matching.fields : 0;

console.log(fields);
```

Comment: why loop over the whole thing when you get a match?

Comment: I already realized that find is better suited than filter, and changed the answer.

Comment: I assume, this is the most efficient and fast solution, isn't it?

Comment: Could be, but hard to say without extensive measuring. For a single run on such a small array, probably most if not all given answers will run in under a millisecond.